# "But had events gone another way"(grammar)

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood, subject-verb-inversion, syntactic-analysis, bare-conditional

The whole sentence is "But had events gone another way, this would be a rather different memoir."

Why is the sentence not like "But the events have gone another way"? "Have" and "events" are reversed, is this first conditional?

Comment: The title of your question mentions **had**, which makes sense. In your question itself you keep mentioning **have**, which makes a lot less sense. Which is it?

Comment: @oerkelens it's "had" in my question, I made a mistake.

Comment: “Had anyone bothered to ask me why, I would have told them.” —— “Were it not for the fire alarm, we would all be dead now.” —— “Be it ever so humble, there’s no place like home.” —— “And come the day you'll hear them saying / ‘They’re throwing it all away’ / Nothing more to say / Just throw it all away.”

Comment: @tchrist Spot of the century?

Comment: There are far more conditionals in Heaven and English than are dreamt of in facilely enumerated ESL gross over-simplifications. You’ve asked a loaded question, so we can’t give you a straight answer.  English conditionals do not require triggers like *if* and *unless*, provided that you have inversion and mood shift.  It has been that way since *Beowulf* and continues so to our own day, albeit perhaps more in literary, poetic, and oratorical registers than in pedestrian banter in the streets and pubs.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth “Lord Grenville”, from *Year of the Cat*.

Comment: @tchrist  I meant the dupe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reversal you noted produces a change in meaning that is equivalent to "But if events had gone another way, [...]"